# Is a textarea's cols attribute supposed to indicate 1 less than the number of columns?

Tags: html, textarea

Every resource I can find says that a textarea's cols attribute indicates the number of average character widths in a horizontal line. Yet, in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (all on OSX), setting a textarea's cols to (eg) 80, with a monospace font, will allow you to type 81 characters before it wraps. It's not a rounding issue; cols=1 adds the same amount. It's not a padding or margin issue either; behavior is the same with all style stripped. And it's only cols, not rows.

Is this specified behavior? If so, why isn't it in the spec, or any of hundreds of online guides / resources? If it's an unofficial convention, is it reliable enough that I can always set cols=79 for 80 columns, instead of setting a css width?

Answer (score 2):

The specified meaning of `cols` is that it “specifies the visible width in average character widths”, and browsers on Windows platform follow this. Of course, if the font is not monospace, the “average character width” becomes a fuzzy concept, and browsers may differ in width allocation.

Wrapping is a different issue. The HTML 4.01 spec still reflects the old idea where no automatic wrapping took place in a textarea, but browsers have generally rejected this. They by default auto-wrap lines longer than the `cols` value, and this is exact on Windows browsers.

Automatic wrapping can be controlled using the `wrap` attribute, which is nonstandard, but `wrap=off` is really the only way to make browsers behave according to the HTML 4.01 “standard”!

In HTML5 drafts, the [`wrap` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-textarea-element.html#attr-textarea-wrap) is defined, but with values `soft` and `hard` only, so it does not describe any way to achieve the old behavior.

As a rule, you should not worry too much about this. Set the `cols` attribute according to what you expect to be most useful to users. A value of 80 is normally far too large; 55 or 60 would correspond to normal optimal line length. And for convenient writing, unless the data is computer code or preformatted text, the font should be set to some proportional font, so that you won’t get an exact maximum amount of characters per line anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The use actually is code entry, so I'm pretty set on exactly 80 columns and a monospace font. So it sounds like you're saying cols won't be exact, and I need to use a css width?

Comment: For a monospace font, `cols` is supposed to be exact, and is exact in the browsers I tested on Windows 7. It sounds like on OS X things might be different. Setting the width in CSS is probably less reliable than the HTML attribute, but you could try the effect of setting `width: 80ch`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for testing in windows. So I guess this is a webkit-OSX bug. I'll set the width in px for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are responsible for this.

1. **Scroll-bar**

   According to W3C there is extra space is for scroll-bar. See notes from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-cols-TEXTAREA).

   > cols = number [CN]
   >
   > This attribute specifies the visible width in average character widths. Users should be able to enter longer lines than this, so user agents should provide some means to scroll through the contents of the control when the contents extend beyond the visible area. User agents may wrap visible text lines to keep long lines visible without the need for scrolling.
2. **Font-size**

   `cols` attribute only works when your font size is `100%` of the browsers default font size. If you change, it wont work. Any implicit/explicit `font-size` css rule will change the behavior.

Comment: It does look like the font size is has a small effect, but not exactly the one you describe. Setting it to "100% of the browser's default font size" does not produce a 1:1 relationship between cols and the actual width. And font-size:90% does not yield 92/.9 = 102 cols.

Comment: @st-boost It also depends on `scroll-bar`!! See my updated answer.

Comment: I had just read that part of the spec, and it seemed to be saying that, instead of forcing users to press return after `cols` characters, browsers should either allow them to either sidescroll or automatically wrap the line. I'm still not sure that's not what it says, but I tried applying "overflow:hidden", and it worked. So, problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: Well I spoke too soon. Problem solved in Firefox. Chrome and Safari didn't react at all.

Comment: @st-boost Chrome also affects as I have tested this on chrome. If you have any `font-size` remove it. implicit font-size will affect too.

Comment: How are you testing it? I'm using [this html](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dWA6QRvq), and still getting the gap in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I have tested it using chrome developer tools.  By setting `overflow:hidden` your overflown content will be hidden it does not do any thing with scroll-bar space.

Comment: [Here's what I see when I load that page](http://i.imgur.com/3HxPn.png). Notice that they both have 81 columns. If that's not what you see, then I guess it's an OSX bug.

Comment: @st-boost this is because its not rendering scroll bar!. Look at this.  http://jsbin.com/emelem/2/#. I used `overflow: auto`. Change it to `overflow: visible` or any other value. I see its rendering scollbar

Comment: It's not rendering the scrollbar because OSX scrollbars are invisible unless you hover over them - you can see that there is a little whitespace reserved for a thin scrollbar. The problem is that webkit still reserves that space, even when the scrollbar will never show up.